# Boolean with loops to check an array

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

Write Java code for a loop that sets boolean variable `isOrdered` to true if the elements of a given array of ints called are in non-decreasing order, otherwise it sets isOrdered to  false.

```java
int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int b = 0;
boolean isOrdered = false;
while (b < i.length) {
    if (i[0] <= i[b]) {
        isOrdered = true;
    }
    b++;
}
out.println(isOrdered);
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: `if (i[0] <= i[b])`  this line is fundamentally flawed in what you are trying to do.

Comment: As is saying `isOrdered = true` based on one comparison. That's the same as saying "if it's not ordered correctly, this pair of elements in the 0th and bth places is ordered correctly"

Comment: This is a good example of a focused well written question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what is wrong.

```
if (i[0] <= i[b])
```

This is the main area which troubles me with your code. How are you checking if the next value you is lower/higher then `i[b]` you are only comparing values at index zero to index b!

Essentially your code would look like this in a loop.

/w `int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`

```
i[0] i[b]
1     1
1     2
1     3
...
```

you get the picture right? What you really need is to check the next value after `b.`

so the code would look like `i[b] > i[b+1]`

Honestly, you could probably make it work on how you initialized the order of `isOrdered` to true and false. I would first initialize it to true. Then the idea is to break out of whatever process you are doing if you find a fallacy in the question with a `false.` Please look at my examples for further *references*.

**iterative**

```
boolean isOrdered = true;

while(isOrdered && array.length - 1 > b){
     if(array[b] > array[b+1]) isOrdered = false;
     b++;
}
```

**recursive**

```
boolean isOrdered(int[] array, index){
    if(index == array.length - 1) return true;
    if(array[index] > array[index + 1]) return false;
    return isOrdered(array, index + 1);
}
```

The recursive method for this is *waaaaaaaaaay* cooler.

Comment: This really isn't a recursive solution, but rather an alternative iterative solution. I like it though.

Comment: @AndyPerfect just added a recursive solution the OP asked for an iterative one so i did that one first :)

Comment: `isOrdered == true` can be just `isOrdered`.

Comment: @Marcelo I always get caught up with `==` i always forget. good catch updated.

Answer (score 0):

No; you are only checking whether the first element of the array is smaller than or equal to at least one of the elements - including the first element itself, which will always be equal to itself, setting `isOrdered` to `true` no matter what the remaining elements are.

Hint #1: you should be comparing every element except the first one with the element immediately before it.

Hint #2: you should be optimistic and assume that the array is ordered, then search for a counter-example. As soon as you found a pair of elements that violate the ordering, set `isOrdered` to false and break out of the loop.

Comment: The reason for Hint #2 is not only an optimization.

In the version from the question, the result is true if ANY of the comparisons succeeds, but I think you only want it to be true if ALL of the comparisons succeed.

Comment: I intended "optimistic" to mean "assume a positive outcome first and then try to find a counter-example"; it has nothing to do with optimization.

Answer (score 0):

do a for loop on the size of the array to check if the next item is less then the current:

```
   int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b = 0;
    boolean isOrdered = true;
    for (int i = 0; i< arr.length - 1 ; i ++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])
        {
            isOrdered = false;
            break;
        }
        b++;
    }
    out.println(isOrdered);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])`

Comment: @Marcelo you are right. did not see that "not" before the decreasing